# Can I make some certain layouts be overlapped by keyboard and some being affected by adjustPan/resize?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I know I can play with `android:windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest, but it affects the whole screen. Can I specify what views should be lifted and what stays behind the keyboard?